# How can I handle Exception in asynchronous python code?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm trying to implement a classic producer and consumer problem.
In the consumer function I initiated a TypeError error, which I want to catch in the result variable in the main function. The code hangs and I can't figure out where the error is. Please help me to understand where the error is.
Code below

```
import asyncio


async def producer(queue):
    for i in range(7):
        await queue.put(i)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.2)
        print('Producer Queue size:', queue.qsize())


async def consumer(queue):
    try:
        while True:
            item = await queue.get()
            await asyncio.sleep(0.3)
            print(item)

            if item is None:
                print('Queue is empty')
                queue.task_done()
                break

            if item == 3:
                raise TypeError("Producer got exception")

            queue.task_done()
            print('Queue size:', queue.qsize())

    except TypeError as e:
        print(f'Error happened asf {e}')
        queue.task_done()
        raise e


async def main():
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    producer_task = asyncio.create_task(producer(queue))
    consumer_task = asyncio.create_task(consumer(queue))

    await asyncio.gather(producer_task)
    await queue.put(None)
    await queue.join()
    consumer_task.cancel()
    result = await asyncio.gather(consumer_task, return_exceptions=True)
    print(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Why don't you just put `result = await asyncio.gather(producer_task, consumer_task, return_exceptions=True)` directly after `queue = ...; producer_task = ...; consumer_task = ...` and remove the rest except for the `print`?

Answer (score 0):

An exception that occurs in an asyncio task is raised when you `await` on the task, and you're never `await`-ing on `consumer`. Additionally, since `consumer` exits before the queue is empty, your call to `await queue.join()` will block forever.

Additionally, your use of `asyncio.gather` with a single task doesn't make any sense; `await asyncio.gather(producer_task)` is equivalent to `await producer_task`.

---

One way of fixing this is to gather results from both `producer` and `consumer` at the same time. If you do this, then it doesn't make sense to `await queue.join()`, because you won't get there until both `producer` and `consumer` are complete. You'll also want to move the `await queue.put(None)` into `producer`.

Implementing those changes gives us:

```
import asyncio


async def producer(queue):
    for i in range(7):
        await queue.put(i)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.2)
        print('Producer Queue size:', queue.qsize())

    await queue.put(None)

async def consumer(queue):
    try:
        while True:
            item = await queue.get()
            await asyncio.sleep(0.3)
            print(item)

            if item is None:
                print('Queue is empty')
                queue.task_done()
                break

            if item == 3:
                raise TypeError("Producer got exception")

            queue.task_done()
            print('Queue size:', queue.qsize())

    except TypeError as e:
        print(f'Error happened asf {e}')
        queue.task_done()
        raise e


async def main():
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    producer_task = asyncio.create_task(producer(queue))
    consumer_task = asyncio.create_task(consumer(queue))

    result = await asyncio.gather(producer_task, consumer_task)
    print("RESULTS:", result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

With the above changes, running your code fails with the expected exception:

```
Error happened asf Producer got exception
Producer Queue size: 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lars/tmp/python/asynctest.py", line 49, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/asyncio/runners.py", line 190, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/asyncio/runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/asyncio/base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/lars/tmp/python/asynctest.py", line 40, in main
    await asyncio.gather(producer_task, consumer_task)
  File "/home/lars/tmp/python/asynctest.py", line 32, in consumer
    raise e
  File "/home/lars/tmp/python/asynctest.py", line 24, in consumer
    raise TypeError("Producer got exception")
TypeError: Producer got exception
```

If we remove the line that generates the `TypeError`, the output looks like:

```
Producer Queue size: 0
0
Queue size: 1
Producer Queue size: 0
1
Queue size: 1
Producer Queue size: 0
Producer Queue size: 1
2
Queue size: 2
Producer Queue size: 1
3
Queue size: 2
Producer Queue size: 1
Producer Queue size: 2
4
Queue size: 3
5
Queue size: 2
6
Queue size: 1
None
Queue is empty
RESULTS: [None, None]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need another communications channel so that the producer, in this case, can know about any information in the consumer side - be it an exception or any other thing.

Follow along: Exceptions exist in a call hierarchy: one function calls another, which call another - when an exception raises, any of the functions on the call stack,  upstream from the place the exception was raised, can handle it. In conventional sync code, that takes place with a try/except block, and in async code, the exception data will be set as attributes on the task object, so that the code which created the task can handle it, if desired.

In this situation, you want to see the exception in a *sibling* task. It does not take any other inputs than the arguments passed at call time: there are no tasks for it to watch for a set "exception", and no code block it can guard in a try/except.

You either need another queue, making the existing connection double-sided, so you can check for signals from the consumer function, or be handled the exception by the `main` function, which can detect the exception in the consumer, and `.throw` it in your consumer.

I think you are thinking in terms of the later - your code can be organized like this, maybe:

(but note that in this design, since you re-raise the exception in the consumer, the consumer itself stops execution and cannot be resumed. You will need a way to signal your `main` function to startover a new consumer anyway)

```
import asyncio


async def producer(queue):
    for i in range(7):
        try:
            print(f"producing {i} ")
            await queue.put(i)
            await asyncio.sleep(0.2)
        except TypeError:
            print("an error took place in the consumer. It is now dead")
        print('Producer Queue size:', queue.qsize())
    # indicates the end of tasks for the consumer:
    queue.put_no_wait(None)


consumer_instance = 0
async def consumer(queue):
    global consumer_instance
    print(f"starting consumer {consumer_instance}")
    consumer_instance += 1
    try:
        while True:
            item = await queue.get()
            await asyncio.sleep(0.3)
            print(item)

            if item is None:
                print('Queue is empty')
                queue.task_done()
                break

            if item == 3:
                raise TypeError("Producer got exception")

            queue.task_done()
            print('Queue size:', queue.qsize())

    except TypeError as e:
        print(f'Error happened asf {e}')
        queue.task_done()
        raise e


async def main():
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    producer_task = asyncio.create_task(producer(queue))
    consumer_task = asyncio.create_task(consumer(queue))

    while True:
        done, pending = await asyncio.wait((producer_task, consumer_task), return_when=asyncio.FIRST_EXCEPTION)
        if consumer_task in done:  # if it is not running, an exception raised in it.
            print(f"caught. {consumer_task.exception()}")
            producer_task.get_coro().throw(consumer_task.exception())
            # you can re-start the consumer here:
            consumer_task = asyncio.create_task(consumer(queue))
        if producer_task in done:
            break

    # await queue.put(None)  #<- moved into the producer, since `wait` needs both tasks to finish.
    await queue.join()
    consumer_task.cancel()
    result = await asyncio.gather(consumer_task, return_exceptions=True)
    print(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```